# how to reuse a method in some other code-behind in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am having a method(C#) in asp.net CodeBehind file. I want to **reuse the same method in some other CodeBehind file**. How is it possible ? And I want to know whether it is appropriate to do so ?

Lets say I am having a method like this. How to reuse this ?

```
protected void button_view(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            hdnViewStatus.Value = "0";
            EmployeeDLL empDll = new EmployeeDLL();
            DataSet ds = empDll.ViewEmployee(Convert.ToInt32(txtEmpId.Text));
            if(ds.Tables.Count!=0)
            {
                lblFirstName.Text = Convert.ToString(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][1]);
                lblLastName.Text = Convert.ToString(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][2]);
                lblMobileNo.Text = (ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][3] == null) ? string.Empty : Convert.ToString(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][3]);
                lblStreetName.Text = Convert.ToString(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][4]);
                lblCity.Text = Convert.ToString(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][5]);
            }
        }
```

Comment: If you're using the exact same labels again, create a UserControl containing all your labels and that method. You can then plug it in both pages.

Comment: @ Pierre  Please forget about the above code. Generally speaking how a method is reused in another codebehind. i.e like calling from another codebehind or something better than that. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a method with public property which used in whole application. Good to create at common place i.e. in a common class(.cs) file.

You can use some method from abstract class too.

1. simple class ( not inherited from any other class )

```
namespace project1
{

   public class ClassName 
   {
        public object Method1(string para1,....)
        {
        }
   }
}
```

2. simple inherited class ( inherited from above class )

`

```
namespace project1
{

    public class ClassName2 : ClassName1
    {
        public object Method2(string para1,....)
        {
          enter code here...
        }
   }
}
```

`
3.  abstract class
for abstract method to reuse, please read links

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf985hc5.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6118/All-about-abstract-classes

Comment: Thank you ajay for your valuable answer :)

Answer (score 1):

The best way to re-use a method is public class or a static class. But, in your case you are using few UI controls such as labels and hidden fields. So, in this case if you need to re-use the same logic (not just the method) you'll have to create a user control with a public property to accept the data set that you are using here. In this user control you'll have your labels and the hidden field.

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y6wb1a0e%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)'s how you'd create a user control.

Hope this helps you to get going.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use this event code in the same page code behind file means, then you create a new method and place this code under that method, and call that method wherever you want....

Answer (score 0):

```
buildConnectionString([...]);

 namespace mafoster_utility
{
    public static class mafoster_utility
    {
    public static string buildConnectionString( string dataSource, string username, string password, string database )
       { 
           //[...]
       }
    }
}
```